How to resolve gradle issue for baseline profile "Code insight is unavailable"?

how to resolve baseline issue code insight unavailable

I tried compatibility to resolve this issue but still getting this error
benchmarkMacroJunit4 = "1.3.3"
baselineprofile = "1.3.0"
profileinstaller = "1.4.1"
agp = "8.7.0"
kotlin = "2.0.0"

